# what is the maximum length for meta_keyword, meta_description and meta_title

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, csv, importexport, meta-tags

While Uploading CSV,

There are some constraints that we have to follow, Like **lengths of the attributes** :

Please Provide the length of following attributes:

"**meta_keyword**"

"**meta_title**"

"**meta_description**"

Attribute Reference from : [Magento Go - Knowledge Base](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/working-with-product-csv-files/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is determined by the database limit for the attributes.

1. `meta_title` has the type `varchar` and is stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. The limit on the `value` field of the table is **255**.
2. `meta_description` and `meta_keywords` have the type `text` and is stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_text`. The limit on the `value` field of the table the limit of the `text` [fields in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). For `text` is "L + 2 bytes, where L < 2<sup>16</sup>".

But the common sense says you shouldn't use large meta keywords and meta descriptions.
A meta description of 255 chars is more than enough.

As for meta keywords...you should ask a SEO expert on this, but I'm sure the recommended number does not go over 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I Think other SEO Sites also suggests for using less than 150 characters.

Comment: Increase length of product *Meta Keywords* field. @Marius